# How do i host mulitiple applications on the same VPS Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do I host multiple applications on the same VPS Python? I use Vultr.com and Ubuntu 20.04 x64. I'm trying to host discord.py bots I can get one of them online at a time.
.

Answer (score 0):

Think you're getting confused here
Vultr.com is a service provider and won't affect the code.

From what it sounds like is your trying to run more than one python scripts ( the discord bots ) at once, try " backgrounding " the scripts one by one.

You can do this by running the script then type Ctrl-Z and then run bg. This has the same effect as running command &

Allowing you to run more than one thing at once

you can also run " nohup command & yourcommandhere " and it will have the same effect as running the script as a background task